# Automatically Reinstantiate a Template Instance in Tosca

Tags: tosca

I am working with a Test Case that takes input from an excel file in Tosca. I'm using a Template Instance so the data from the excel gets loaded and I can use it in my test case. I know I can reinstantiate the Instance by clicking on the Reinstantiate button, but I'm running the Test Case from an external source, so I can't go to Tosca and click the button every time I need to update the input (the data of the excel input is different every time I run it). 
Is there a way to make Tosca automatically Reinstantiate the Template Instance every time I run it?

Answer (score 0):

No, unforunately there is NO way to do it automatically. It is not even possible without a great effort to (re)instantiate several templates at once.